# Adding legend to ggplot for clearity

Tags: legend

so I need to add a legend to this. I have the feeling I am doing something wrong with the aes() function, but I could be wrong. Here is my code:

```
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)

Mydata <- read_excel('../...') #Data file
df <- subset(data.frame(x1 = Mydata$rc, y1 = Mydata$`O2 (mol/m^3)`), y1 > 0.051 & x1 > 0)         #Points that do count
df2 <- subset(data.frame(x2 = Mydata$rc, y2 = Mydata$`O2 (mol/m^3)`), y2 < 0.051 & y2 > 0)        #Point not taken into account
cols = c('Included in regression' = 'blue', 'Excluded from regression' = 'blue')
fills = c('Included in regression' = 'blue', 'Excluded from regression' = 'white')

ggplot()+
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x1,y1), color = 'blue')+
  geom_point(data = df2, aes(x2,y2), color = 'blue', pch = 1)+
  geom_path(data = df, aes(x1,y1), color = 'blue')+
  geom_smooth(data = df, aes(x1,y1), formula = y~x, method = 'lm', se = FALSE, color = 'red')+
  stat_poly_eq(data = df, formula = y~x, rr.digits = 3, coef.digits = 5,
               aes(x1,y1, label = paste("atop(", after_stat(eq.label), ",", after_stat(rr.label), ")", sep = "")), 
               parse = TRUE, label.x = 'right')+
  xlab(expression('dC'[O2]*'/dt (mol m'^-3*' s'^-1*')'))+
  ylab(expression('C'['O2']*' (mol m'^-3*')'))+
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 0.00205),ylim = c(0,0.27),expand = c(0,0))+
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your `color = '<color>'` statements inside `aes()`.   For example,

```
geom_point(data = df, aes(x1,y1,color = 'blue'))
```

It's likely your going to want to manage the labels in the legend.  In this case, you can use

```
geom_point(data = df, aes(x1,y1,color = 'mylabel')) + 
scale_color_manual(values=c('mylabel'='blue'))
```

and the legend label will be `"mylabel"`.

Comment: Thanks for the reaction! I tried this, but then the colour disappears from my points themselves. I need to make clear that I want to have both the points the same colour, blue. However, the one of the first set should be filled by the same colour blue, while the other should be white/transparent.

Comment: Can you modify your code to include a reproducible example? 
I can't "Mydata <- read_excel('../...') #Data file"